# $gt operation failing on a field which is of long datatype in PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, google-cloud-composer

I have been facing issue while filtering or performing incremental pull on MongoDB collection based on `createdTimestamp` column. The value in the column is of Epoch time format. I need to perform `$gt` operation to pull data greater than stored max epoch time. While performing `$gt`, i am getting below error

```
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: Decimal('1675286325369'), of type: <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

`cursor = collection.find({})`
Full load using this works

```
query = {"createdTimeStamp": {"$gt": max_created_date}}

cursor = collection.find(query)
```

Incremental pull with `$gt` doesn't work
Note: `max_created_date` is epoch time value i.e `1675286325369`

Comment: For some reason, `max_created_date` is of class `decimal.Decimal`.  `pymongo` doesn't know how to encode that into BSON.  You could _"teach"_ `pymongo` how to encode it by defining a custom [`bson.codec_options.TypeEncoder`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/codec_options.html#bson.codec_options.TypeEncoder)(similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74356235/1409374)), or you could more simply use `query = {"createdTimeStamp": {"$gt": int(max_created_date)}}`.

Comment: Thank you so much @rickhg12hs, your solution worked. Apologies for reaching out late for confirming on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pymongo` doesn't natively know how to convert objects of type `decimal.Decimal` to a proper BSON data type.

You could "teach" `pymongo` how to encode it by defining a custom [`bson.codec_options.TypeEncoder`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/codec_options.html#bson.codec_options.TypeEncoder) (similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74356235/1409374)), or you could more simply use:

```python
query = {"createdTimeStamp": {"$gt": int(max_created_date)}}
```

This will convert `max_created_date` from `decimal.Decimal` to `int` and `pymongo` knows how to encode that into proper BSON.