# How to configure pymongo to automatically marshal and unmarshal protobufs

Tags: python, mongodb, protocol-buffers, pymongo

I'd like to have protobuf support in pymongo. Specifically, I want to be able to pass protobufs anywhere that I could pass a dict (such as `collection.insert_one()`) and I want to get the appropriate protobuf instance anywhere I'd otherwise get a dict (such as `collection.find_one()`).

So far, for my proof of concept, I'm able to do this by converting the protobuf to a Python dict (using `json_format.MessageToDict()`) and then passing the dict to pymongo, and vice versa. This double-conversion is hacky, inefficient, and I haven't been able to get it to handle all the datatypes I want (such as the binary formats). By "double conversion" I mean that I'm converting first to `dict` then to the final structure (either `protobuf` or `BSONDocument`). The major downside here is that despite calling the function `MessageToDict()`, the protobuf `json_format` library converts to a *json-safe* dict -- `bytes` are converted to base64, `int64`s are converted to strings, etc.

I found somebody who seems to have [done this in golang](https://dataform.co/blog/mongodb-protobuf-codec). (Note that my primary goal is to marshal and unmarshal, not to do the protobuf ID reflection as in his example.) I found the [pymongo docs on custom types](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/custom_type.html) but the way I understand the docs is that the [`TypeCodec` class](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/codec_options.html#bson.codec_options.TypeCodec) is only for individual types (such as `Decimal`) and **not** for the entire message / document. I also found `document_class` but that appears to be [only for decoding and requires a subclass of `MutableMapping`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/540562a60630a57d3eb0c06358b19d3882a5de18/bson/codec_options.py#L289), which generated protobufs are not.

I found `bson.encode()` and `bson.decode()` but, short of monkeypatching, it's not clear  how I would override or configure these.

Comment: _"... I want to be able to pass protobufs anywhere that I could pass a dict ..."_  _anywhere_? ... or just insertion and retrieval? _" ... double-conversion is hacky ..."_ I don't think there is a choice since the MongoDB server deals in BSON only.  Under-the-hood, all Mongodb drivers must use some CODEC between BSON and the driver/client language data types.  _" ... done this in golang."_ At the time of the article (see second to last paragraph), it does look like they implemented a full CODEC, but had no easy method to query the database since all the field names are transformed.

Comment: There are several Python methods/packages available to transform protobufs to Dicts and vice-versa.  If you only want to store/retrieve the protobufs, that should not be too difficult.  But, if you want to query the individual protobuf fields, I didn't see any packages/libraries that would transform protobuf-like queries into MQL/BSON queries.  It seems like it would be possible, but many `pymongo` classes would need to be subclassed (or something like that) to handle the protobuf/BSON transformation.

Comment: When I say "double conversion", I mean BSON -> dict -> protobuf (and then protobuf -> dict -> BSON on the way back). I want BSON <> protobuf. What I'm looking for is, basically, a CODEC that does BSON <> protobfuf instead of BSON <> dict. I can even write the CODEC myself but I can't figure out how to register it. The documentation suggests that CODECs are just for fields (e.g. `Decimal`).

Comment: I'm wondering if a CODEC could be written for protobuf <--> [BSON Binary with a user defined subtype](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/index.html#bson.Binary).

Comment: Besides the `TypeCodec` docs you've already looked at, and the examples there, here's another [trivial example of a custom `TypeDecoder`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74356235/1409374) with minimal code showing its use with a collection.

Comment: Thanks, but everything I understand about `TypeCodec`, and reaffirmed by the example you linked, is that it's for **types** (like `Decimal` or `ObjectId`) and not the entire message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find anything that converted directly between bson<>protobuf, but I did find [this old package](https://github.com/benhodgson/protobuf-to-dict) to convert between bson<>dict. Unlike Google's `json_format` module, `protobuf-to-dict` does not helpfully convert datatypes which aren't in the JSON spec (e.g., `int64`s). (And it allows you to override the type converters if desired.)

While I'd still prefer not to have to convert via a Python dict, the use of this package solves the major problems around undesired type conversion, so I cleaned it up a bit, updated it to py3 (which was trivial), and took out the base64 binary conversions.